# Moodle- Front page Customization

Tags: javascript, php, moodle, bootstrapping

I am facing problem with my Front page of moodle. It display all the enrolled courses when i changed setting from Site Administration->Front page->Front page settings(Screenshot attached) for enrolled user.
[image: Front Page error]

But When i created new user and not assigned any single course to him/her. It displays Available course. It should be display "No courses available". Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Just added `display:none;` in `$header = '<div id="frontpage-course-list">';` of directory theme/yourtheme/renderers/course_renderer.php